# STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW error, cannot continue working (Angular)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Got this error in the console, tried to solve it with usual methods, but it didn't help.

STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW. It's what's shown in the browser.

Below it's what's shown in the console. Any suggestions? I cannot solve it

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at LComponentView_RecipeListComponent.concat (<anonymous>)
    at cloneToLViewFromTViewBlueprint (core.js:6483)
    at createLView (core.js:7444)
    at addComponentLogic (core.js:8582)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:8415)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7784)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14528)
    at ɵɵelement (core.js:14579)
    at RecipeListComponent_Template (template.html:4)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7757)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:4127
push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:4175
(anonymous) @ core.js:28820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:386
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:143
push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:28084
(anonymous) @ core.js:28820
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:386
onInvoke @ core.js:28144
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:385
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:143
(anonymous) @ zone.js:891
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:421
onInvokeTask @ core.js:28132
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:420
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:188
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:584
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:231
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:251
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:881
ZoneAwarePromise.then @ zone.js:1027
push../node_modules/@angular/core/__ivy_ngcc__/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:28741
./src/main.ts @ main.ts:11
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
0 @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79
checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32
(anonymous) @ main.js:1
main.ts:12 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at LComponentView_RecipeListComponent.concat (<anonymous>)
    at cloneToLViewFromTViewBlueprint (core.js:6483)
    at createLView (core.js:7444)
    at addComponentLogic (core.js:8582)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.js:8415)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.js:7784)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.js:14528)
    at ɵɵelement (core.js:14579)
    at RecipeListComponent_Template (template.html:4)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:7757)
```

Comment: Please include the code that caused this error. Also, STACK OVERFLOW. *roll credits*

Comment: Start your quest by checking what is on `template.html` line 4, and work you way back. Remark lines of code to check if the error disappears or changes.

Comment: Based on message 'Maximum call stack size exceeded', it seems you have problem with infinite loop or recursion. I suggest to go through createLView component and up, to locate this error. Hope this helps

Comment: Okay, but the trick is also that I haven’t changed the files that you mentioned, but I will look

Comment: <div class="col-md-5">
        <app-recipe-list></app-recipe-list>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <app-recipe-detail></app-recipe-detail>
    </div>

Comment: It caused an error, but it's too simple

Comment: So check every line of app-recipe-detail, the infinite loop is in that code. Put `console.log('im here!')` somewhere in the code, check if it reached that point in your console.

Comment: It could be in `<app-recipe-list>` and in `<app-recipe-detail>`, remark te list first, if the error is not there, it's in the list component.

Comment: okay, the thing is that, there is only the created component (and the basic code in it), so how there can be an infinite loop?

Comment: Mostly when a component is calling a child component, and that child is calling the parent again. But unless you are sharing some of your code, that is only a guess.

Comment: I got the idea, have you ever had the same?

Comment: I don't share any code anywhere, and the components are created via console

Comment: More than once... Mistakes should make us better programmers, but I keep making the same every time :)

Comment: Put `console.log('yes')` somewhere in the code, and check it it reaches it, and move it around in your code, until you understand what is happening. `console.log(someVar)` helps too.

Comment: I know this method, but hoped that my case will be enough simple solve it in other way

Comment: We can't help you with code, if you don't share some code samples in your question. What did you try, what is the basic setup of your app, and so on. We need to see the code to understand what the error trace is about.
Glad to help, but we just need more than a trace log. We need the code behind it too in a basic layout/setup

Comment: Agree, for now, the all I can add is that without the code mentioned above, everything works fine

Comment: So the error is triggered in one of the two components used in that line.

Comment: Ok, so I will simply redo them)

Comment: I solved the issue by redoing the components and reinstalling dependencies, probably problem was with them

Answer (score 0):

A very common root cause for this is the use of a selector, within the same component template. It sounds really simple, but sometimes it is difficult to catch and can be time consuming.

Below is an example of what I mean for better clarity:

**app.component.ts**

```
 @Component({
    selector: "app-component",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["app.component.css"]
 })

...
```

On the above component note that the selector is `app-component` and the template related to the app.component.ts is the `app.component.html`.

Now, if you were to put the selector within the actual HTML of the template, the browser window would crash with the `STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW` error.

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h2>Below notice the selector of the same component, which causes a 
  STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW error</h2>
  
  <app-component></app-component>
</div>
```

I've seen people spending hours on errors like that, and frankly speaking these errors can be easily overlooked.